# How to control the maximum number of iterations in scipy's solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am wondering how I can limit the number of iterations that `solve_ivp` takes for an integration step or set a minimum step size. I am running a calibration and I want to prevent the solver from taking very long if my parameters lead to a system where integration is difficult.

There is as `min_step` argument but this only applies to the LSODA solver and I am using BDF (since my system is stiff). For the old `odeint` I could also choose a maximum number of integration steps, but that does not seem to exist in `solve_ivp`.
Does anyone know how the solver actually decides when to interrupt the integration because it is not successful?

Comment: Can you also try the implicit `radau` method and what your measured number of function evaluations is? If you have a chemical reaction system, the equations should be of the form `dcA/dt = cA*(...)`. If so, you can change to exponential parametrization `cA=exp(uA)` that has the positivity explicitly enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the parameter

```
rtol, atol : float and array_like, optional
```

I assume setting a larger tolerance might also speed up the process.

Comment: I think this is not what I need. I want to prevent the solver from making tiny steps or taking a huge number of iterations. As far as I understand it, the parameter `max_step` only prevents that integration steps become too large.

Comment: Probably I should adjust my tolerances more but increasing them does not necessarily help. I actually decreased them to prevent getting simply wrong results (negative concentrations) -- and that even sped up the simulations. But I think there should be a separate parameter that simply allows stopping the integration when the steps become too small.